# Cordova Screen Orientation Plugin error lockOrientation() is not available on this device

Tags: cordova, screen-orientation

Cordova Screen Orientation Plugin  working correctly at first time.But after close the app and open it again the plugin shows error like this 
lockOrientation() is not available on this device.My platform is android

app.js

```
 controller:function() {
        screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
        // access current orientation
        console.log('Orientation is ' + screen.orientation.type);
    },
```

config.xml

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

I need portrait mode only in first two screen.After that screens I need landscape mode.so I decide to change portrait mode to landscape at controller

CONSOLE SHOWS 
Orientation is portrait-primary